# Failed to mount local volume error while installing ElasticSearch docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, mount

I'm following steps to setup 3 Linux node cluster for ElasticSearch & Kibana using docker-compose. During the process, while running a command "docker-compose -f create-certs.yml run --rm create_certs", gets below output with Error:

```
Creating network "es-dev_elastic" with driver "overlay"
Creating volume "es-dev_config" with local driver
Pulling create_certs (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.6)...
Trying to pull repository docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch ...
7.17.6: Pulling from docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
<Some-ID>: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:<Some-ID>
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.6
**ERROR: Cannot create container for service create_certs: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/elasticmount/es11/config:/var/lib/docker/volumes/es-dev_config/_data, flags: 0x1000:                                                 no such file or directory**
```

I didn't created any local volume mounts before it. So, if this is the issue

**How & where to create & mount the directory in docker?**

Answer (score 2):

You want to create 3 nodes of elasticsearch along with kibana if i am not wrong.
Below I am providing a docker-compose file that will help you to create 3 nodes cluster of elasticsearch with kibana.

```html
version: "3"
services:
  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://127.0.0.1:9200
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5601:5601
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "-Des.logger.level=DEBUG"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: elasticsearch2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet
  elasticsearch3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: elasticsearch3
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet


volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
  esdata2:
    driver: local
  esdata3:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

This will create 3 named volumes (esdata1,esdata2,esdata3) and this volumes will be created at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can put all variable like elk version which in your compose file to `.env` file.